# script.bundle.js file not getting triggered when performing event in dynamic form

Tags: html, image, forms, dynamic, bundle

**image wrapper not changing blank image to selected image**
*When I  try to change image in my dynamically generated form all fields are input and those are working but the image select is not working and the styling for dropdown not getting applied which also is in bundle.cs file*

```
       case "Image":
                                    formHtml.Append($@"
                             <div class='col-md-6 text-md-end pb-0'>
                             <div class='image-input image-input-outline image-input-circle' data-           kt-image-input='true'>
                                        <div class='image-input-wrapper w-80px h-80px badge badge-circle image-input image-input-empty image-input-outline' id='kt_image_5' style='background-image: url(/assets/media/avatars/blank.png)'>

                                    </div>
                                    <label class='btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-active-color-primary w-25px h-25px bg-body shadow' data-kt-image-input-action='change' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' aria-label='Change photo' data-bs-original-title='Change avatar' data-kt-initialized='1'>
                                        <i class='ki-duotone ki-pencil fs-7'><span class='path1'></span><span class='path2'></span></i>
                                        <input type='file' name='{DataColumn}' DataColumn='{DataColumn}' accept='.png, .jpg, .jpeg'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='{DataColumn}'>
                                    </label>
                                    <span class='btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-active-color-primary w-25px h-25px bg-body shadow' data-kt-image-input-action='cancel' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' aria-    label='Cancel photo' data-bs-original-title='Cancel avatar' data-kt-initialized='1'>
                                        <i class='ki-duotone ki-cross fs-2'><span class='path1'></span><span class='path2'></span></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class='btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-active-color-primary w-25px h-25px bg-body shadow' data-kt-image-input-action='remove' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' aria-label='Remove avatar' data-bs-original-title='Remove avatar' data-kt-initialized='1'>
                                        <i class='ki-duotone ki-cross fs-2'><span class='path1'></span><span class='path2'></span></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                ");
                                    break;
```

*instead of using  this image wrapper I simply used *

```
<input type='file' alt='img'/>
```

*it is selecting an image but using above code the image is not getting selected I want it change when I try to change it from blank to the selected image and same for the country styling*